# Shell scripts with Git Bash 64-bit on Windows

Tags: windows, git, bash, shell, mingw-w64

I've installed Git Bash 2.5.1 64-bit on a fresh Windows 10 machine:

```
mark@Foo MINGW64 ~/Documents/FsCheck (master)
$ git --version
git version 2.5.1.windows.1
```

When I list the contents of a directory, I can see a shell script:

```
mark@Foo MINGW64 ~/Documents/FsCheck (master)
$ ls
appveyor.yml  build.cmd  build.sh*         Docs/
bin/          build.fsx  Contributors.txt  examples/  FsCheck.sln
```

(Some files and folders removed for clarity.)

Notice that the shell script `build.sh` has an asterisk after the extension. In the console, it's also coloured green, where other files are light grey. I haven't seen this before, so I don't know if it means anything.

When I try to run the script, I get an error message:

```
mark@Foo MINGW64 ~/Documents/FsCheck (master)
$ build.sh
bash: build.sh: command not found
```

Also, there's no tab completion for any of the `build` files.

How can I run the shell script from Git Bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have `ls` aliased to `ls -F`. So when an trailing asterisk appears that means that the file is executable.

In POSIX systems, you can't directly execute files in current directory (for safety reasons). If you want to, you can use this trick:

```
./build.sh
```

Comment: That's different from how Git Bash (32-bit, I think) has recently worked for me, but it works, and I learned something new today, so I'm happy. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, I just run into the same error, after installing the latest Git and having it use [MinTTY](https://mintty.github.io/) instead of cmd.exe. This worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, edit your PATH by adding ";." at the END of the current value.  In mingw64_shell.bat do

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;.
```

**Note**: I'm looking at my MSYS2 installation, so you may need to look for the ".bat" file that launches bash.  The biggest security problem with the WINDOWS default path that had "." in front of the path is that it allows a user to over-ride a system executable -- that would make your scripts do some weird stuff, especially if you import them from someone else.